# How to make load more button,showing other rows?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't get the code right for my page.

I have 6 rows with 3 columns each, filled with images. When I click "load more" button it doesn't do anything. I tried to change jquery code `.slice(0, 3)` to `(0, 6)` etc, but nothing. I need to show only 2 or 3 rows, then when I click load more button, show another 2 or 3 more rows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row").slice(0, 3).show();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".row:hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown();
    if ($(".row:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Grid row -->



<div class="row">

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">

    <!-- Card -->
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModalo">

      <!-- Card image -->
      <img class="card-img-top" height="350" src="images/lule_1.jpg" alt="Card imgage lule">

      <!-- Card content -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Phone Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag,Box</p>
      </div>

    </a>
    <!-- Card -->

    <!-- Card -->
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal">

      <!-- Card image -->
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/lule_4.jpg" alt="Card image lule">

      <!-- Card content -->
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Paper Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag</p>
      </div>

    </a>

    <!-- Card -->

    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>


  </div>

  <!-- Grid column -->
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] from it

Comment: It seems that you only make hidden rows visible rather than really load new ones. Is there any point in it?

Comment: thank you very much,but i cant fix it,never mind,i will try something else.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you,second time using stack overflow and english it's not my native language

Comment: @kristipapaqako Your English is ok if you just follow the suggestions I gave you :)

Comment: However we try to help you and you go "never mind" instead of telling us what did not work for you...

Comment: i didn't mean to offend you all,but i have a huge code and i cant write it all,for you to see

Comment: and i cant find the problem for my page,"never mind" in my contry is used to say,thank you but dont worry,anyway sorry,i cant explain the problem in english.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two way ,

first - initially hide all rows then show first 3

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".row").hide(); //add this line
$(".row").slice(0, 3).show();
$("#loadMore").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".row:hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown();
 if($(".row:hidden").length == 0) {
   $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
 }
});

})
```

second - hide last three first

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".row").slice(3, 6).hide();//change this line
$("#loadMore").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".row:hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown();
 if($(".row:hidden").length == 0) {
   $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
 }
});

})
```

Comment: thank you very much,but i cant fix it,never mind,i will try something else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know jQuery but I wrote it in standard JavaScript, hope it helps!

```
        document.querySelector('#loadMore').addEventListener('click', (button) =>{
            //Set number of rows to show
            const numRowsToShow = 2
            for (let i = 0; i < numRowsToShow; i++) {
                
                //Get the next row non visible (.d-none)
                let rowToShow = document.querySelector('.row.d-none')
                
                //If nothing's found change the text of the link and exit the loop
                if(!rowToShow){
                    
                    button.target.text = 'No Content'
                    button.classList.add('noContent')
                    break;                    
                } 

                //show the row
                rowToShow.classList.remove('d-none')
            }
        })
```

Comment: thank you very much,but i cant fix it,never mind,i will try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = $(".row").toArray();
  $(".row").hide();
  $(rows.splice(0, 1)).show();
  $(document).on("click", "#loadMore",  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!rows.length) {
      $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
    } else {
      $(this).remove();
      $(rows.splice(0, 1)).slideDown();
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModalo">
      <img class="card-img-top" height="350" src="images/lule_1.jpg" alt="Card imgage lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Phone Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag,Box</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/lule_4.jpg" alt="Card image lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Paper Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModalo">
      <img class="card-img-top" height="350" src="images/lule_1.jpg" alt="Card imgage lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Phone Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag,Box</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/lule_4.jpg" alt="Card image lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Paper Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModalo">
      <img class="card-img-top" height="350" src="images/lule_1.jpg" alt="Card imgage lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Phone Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag,Box</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/lule_4.jpg" alt="Card image lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Paper Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModalo">
      <img class="card-img-top" height="350" src="images/lule_1.jpg" alt="Card imgage lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Phone Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag,Box</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="card hoverable mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/lule_4.jpg" alt="Card image lule">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="my-3">Paper Bag</h5>
        <p class="card-text text-uppercase mb-3">Bag</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much,but i cant fix it,never mind,i will try something else.

Comment: @kristipapaqako Why can't it be fixed?

Comment: 1 min,i will try that again

Comment: @kristipapaqako Is the HTML structure of your code similar to the one in my snippet?

Comment: yes it is,if is possible can i send you an email with my work to see it better?,becouse i cant find te problem.thank you

Comment: @kristipapaqako Yeah, you can mail me, or share some link for some fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222375/discussion-between-pranav-rustagi-and-kristi-papaqako).